# I want to use my app to link to Google action

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

How to call Google home action directly. I want to click the external connection to jump directly to action。***emphasized text***

Comment: Please add more details or code snippets of what you've tried to your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I have an app. I hope that when my users click a button on my app, they can directly jump to the action I created on Google home

Comment: I tried to use the following two links to jump to Google home app, but I couldn't activate my action https://madeby.google.com/home-app/?deeplink= and https://assistant.google.com/services/a/id

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the deep link within your app to link to your Action's OAuth flow, as described in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/discovery#deep-linking).

Your link should be formatted similar to the following:

```
https://madeby.google.com/home-app/?deeplink=setup%2Fha_linking%3Fagent_id%3Dagent-id
```

The `agent-id` is returned in your `SYNC` response, and is typically your project ID in the Actions console ([reference docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/sync?hl=en) for `SYNC` response).